# Can't configure ZigBee SZ05-ADV module with X-CTU and can't use XBee API in Arduino

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee, firmware

I have few ZigBee modules to work with but these are not the contemporary digi modules. It has its own firmware installed and has their own terminal program to configure it their way. But every where on the internet, all the tutorials are about digi modules and X-CTU. I can neither make this module work with Arduino XBee API not with X-CTU.

Well, I can broadcast and receive data to a single network using the SoftSerial library but can't change the pan id, or configure the modules from inside Arduino as I can't make use of the XBee API library with this ZigBee module. Anyone has any idea? Or if I try resetting the firmware with the ones available in X-CTU, will it make sense? Provided, I am new to working with XBee.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Nafis! If you don't get the answer you're looking for here, please consider posting your question at [Arduino StackExchange site](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this ZigBee SZ05-ADV with X-CTU since it isn't a Digi product. Take a look at the [User Manual](http://www.tato.ind.br/files/SZ05%20product%20manual.pdf) which show how to configure your module, but I will try to resume it for you:

You need to connect your computer to this module by serial interface communication (e.g. use Hyper Terminal); Use the following configuration: Baud rate: 38400, Data Bit: 8, parity: NONE, Stop Bit: 1, Flow: NONE.

Once you are connected, it shows the default settings:

[image: settings]

So you can "talk" to your module to configure and/or change de PAN ID (option 5).

Please read the complete [User Manual](http://www.tato.ind.br/files/SZ05%20product%20manual.pdf) for more information.